# Web api call works locally but not on Azure

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service

I have same issue as per following questions and tried answer but never resolve issue

[Web api interface works locally but not on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494678/web-api-interface-works-locally-but-not-on-azure)

[Web API interface works locally but gets 404 after deployed to Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418344/web-api-interface-works-locally-but-gets-404-after-deployed-to-azure-website)

and many more similar type of...

When i tried to call api it says 404 Not Found

my WebApi.config file

```
// Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "versionApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

API Controller

```
[Authorize]
[RequiresSSL]
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/Configuration")]
public class ConfigurationAPIv2Controller : ApiController
{
    [Dependency]
    public IConfigurationServicev2 configurationService { get; set; }

    [Dependency]
    public IAccountService accountService { get; set; }


    #region testapi

    [Route("getstring")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult getstring()
    {
        return Ok("Success");
    }


    [Route("putstring")]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult putstring()
    {
        return Ok("Success");
    }
    #endregion
```

And Folder Structure is like :

[image]

i got follwowing issue for both get and Put method
[image]

Comment: even if I am tried by removing [Authorize] and [RequiresSSL] attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 error might caused by route issue. Since you are using route attribute for your Web API. Please make sure GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); is above other code.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

And config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); code is above other routes configuration.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "versionApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In addition, try to delete following code in your Controller to test whether it is related to the dependent injection module.

```
[Dependency]
public IConfigurationServicev2 configurationService { get; set; }

[Dependency]
public IAccountService accountService { get; set; }
```

If it also can't work for you. You could get the detail error message from web server after setting IncludeErrorDetailPolicy property in WebApiConfig class.

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

Comment: tried as per your answer , but same issue , Header                    
Request URL:https://XXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/v2/configuration/Employee/1747
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:23.100.46.198:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade   Even for the normal testapi controller with simple get method

Comment: [RoutePrefix("api/v2/test")]
    public class testapiController : ApiController
    {

        #region testapi

        [Route("getstring")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult getstring()
        {
            return Ok("Success");
        }


        [Route("putstring")]
        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult putstring()
        {
            return Ok("Success");
        }
        #endregion
    }

Comment: clear git repo and re-push required files only and it works -  as i used Continuous Deployment to Azure functionality

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not add a default.html page to wwwroot and IIS does.

Just add **default.html** page to **wwwroot** in your project, then re-deploy to Azure.