# WebAPI Routes not being recognized on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to deploy a WebAPI project to Azure.

It works locally. When I `Publish` it to Azure, I get 404 on the controller routes.

Looking at the logs, I see the routes are being handled as static files, instead of going through my controllers.

`Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://xxxxx:80/api/studies
Physical Path      D:\home\site\wwwroot\api\studies
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous`

My Global.asax is:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

And my WebApiConfig.Register is:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I've looked at similar questions and tried tweaking my Web.config to no avail. It currently looks like this (relevant part only):

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

By the way, I'm on Entity Framework 6 and not using MVC, just straight up WebAPI.

Comment: What does the controller (studies) look like?

Comment: Just the usual thing you'd get when scaffolding a controller.

Comment: Are you using any form of OWIN middleware? Is there any Startup class in your Web API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow my `Global.asax` got excluded from the project, so the route mapping never happened.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. nothing else worked until changing my web config to look like this solved it for me

```
<handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all the necessary Windows Features for your server? Maybe some features are missing from IIS, for example:
Internet Information Services - World Wide Web Services - Application Development Features - ASP.NET.
You can find and check which features are installed on your machine by going to Windows Features (or going through the Server Manager if you're on a Windows Server).

If that is not your problem, it can sometimes be that ASP.NET is not installed properly. You can re-install ASP.NET by following this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736284 (it depends on your operating system).

Comment: I am using Azure Websites, so it abstracts aways the "Windows Features" thing. I'm pretty sure it automatically configures IIS, ASP.NET etc.

Comment: It may be some problem with the publish-tool. Can you try deleting all *.dll files in your bin directory, Rebuild and then publish again? You can also check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418344/web-api-interface-works-locally-but-gets-404-after-deployed-to-azure-website

Comment: Tried deleting all bin/*.dll, didn't make a difference.

Comment: Checked all answers to the question you posted, nothing works.